# Optimizing multiple whereHas queries

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My model has a relationship with an attribute model. Each attribute has its own values.
I execute a query like this, but it is very slow.

```
foreach($request->input('attributes') as $id => $value) {
   $products->whereHas('attributes', function ($q) use ($id, $value) {
         q->where('attributes.id', $id)
          ->whereRaw('CAST(value AS DECIMAL(10,2)) between ? and ?', $value);
       );
    }
```

Is there any way to optimize?

Comment: Are you sure it is the query that is slow? It could be slow because of other reasons e.g. having many lazy load models in the template within a for loop.

Comment: If attributes in request more than 20, i get error "MySQL Server Has Gone Away". I think I can somehow move foreach into whereHas.